# How to holds correctly the state of Android applications

Tags: android, state

My app have three views

- Choose A
- Choose B
- RepeatView (Based on A and B)
- ResultView

The main core of my app will appear on RepeatView but Choose A and Choose B will define how the RepeatView behaves also RepeatView will appear many times and ResultView will appear at the end

my question is: How to handle the state of the App that efficiently that allow me access to the state of the app from all views?

**Update**

this is a very basic example of the state. based on what users chooses on A and B I'll populate repeats

```
class State  {
  public int chooseA;
  public int chooseB;
  public String[] repeats;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it in your application instance,  and reload it in a BaseActivity in onRestoreInstanceState only if it's still null.  That's a possible solution,  for example.